# Include files from parent directory

Tags: php

I'm facing a problem using relative path...I have that directory structure

```
-dev
 --vendor
   -autoload.php
 --includes
   -index.php
```

now i need to include autoload.php in index.php
As adviced on previous answers i tried `include('../vendor/autoload.php');` but it didnt work.

but this didnt work so i had to use this walkaround `require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/dev/vendor/autoload.php');`

So im wondering why the relative path didnt work and how to make it work?

Comment: Which previous answers are you asking about here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only thing that comes to my mind right now is the current working directory.

If you don't specify an absolute path the current working directory will be chosen.

E.g.

```php
<?php
chdir("/tmp");
include "test.php"; // will include /tmp/test.php
```

And

```php
<?php
chdir("/home/marco");
include "test.php"; // will include /home/marco/test.php
```

Try changing your path to: `__DIR__."/../vendor/autoload.php"`.

See [PHP: Magic Constants](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php) for further reference.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, it works perfectly for me